# Unittest in Clojure doesn't compile when I test my own functions

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I am new to Clojure and now I'm trying to use some unittesting.

I have a sample project with this structure:

[image: structure of my sample project]

core.clj in src/hello contains

```
(ns hello.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn side-eq [x]
  (if (< 0 (count x)) 
    (= (.charAt x 0) (.charAt x (- (count x) 1)))
    false))
```

core.clj in test/hello contains

```
(ns hello.core    
  (:use clojure.test)
  (:require [hello.core :refer :all])
  (:gen-class))


(use 'clojure.test)
(deftest side-eq-tests (
                         is (= false (side-eq "aws"))))

(run-tests)
```

when I execute tests, it throws

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: side-eq in this context**

When I test something like

```
is (= 1 1)
```

then everything works fine.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have multiple files with the same namespace. Rename your tests to something else. The idiomatic name here would be `hello.core-test` In `test/hello/core_test.clj`

Answer (score 0):

A variation which I prefer is to begin all testing namespacese with the `tst.*` prefix, which avoids the hyphen-underscore conversion & confusion (e.g. `demo.core-test` vs `demo.core_test.clj`.  So your files look like so:

```
> d **/*.clj
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan 1024 Jan  5 19:00 project.clj*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan   84 Jan  5 15:29 src/demo/core.clj*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan alan  248 Jan  7 12:42 test/tst/demo/core.clj*
```

and the code looks like:

```
(ns demo.core)

(defn -main []
  (println "main - enter")
)
```

and

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.misc :as tm] ))

....
```